# Issue with MQTT to Logstash Configuration - Unknown settings error

Tags: logstash, mqtt

I'm using the following Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  mqtt {
    client_id => "logstash"
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 1883
    topics => ["/Application1/Message"]
    qos => 1
    id => "mqtt_input"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "test.logstash"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "xyz"
  }
}
```

Error Received:
I'm receiving the following errors when running Logstash:

```
[ERROR][logstash.inputs.mqtt] Unknown setting 'host' for mqtt
[ERROR][logstash.inputs.mqtt] Unknown setting 'topics' for mqtt
```

Troubleshooting Attempts:

I've checked the Logstash documentation and MQTT input plugin, but I couldn't find any discrepancies in the configuration.
I also tried adjusting the configuration as per documentation, but the issue persists.
Additional Information:

Logstash version: logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64

MQTT Input plugin version:
[image]

Can someone assist in understanding why Logstash is throwing these unknown setting errors for the MQTT input plugin configuration? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.